# NodeJs with express tracking read and unread messages

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, sendgrid

Please, I am building app which I want to display messages which are read and unread from the server to the user view.
How I do that? Please any help.

Thanks

Comment: do you wanted to display message on web page is it.? if so. you can add any flag something like read: true or false in database (MongoDB/ MySQL any other db which you wanted to persist the data)

by default when show message on screen that mail's flag read would be false (read: false). and whenever user clicks on the email list (on opening email from list) just update the flag of individual email to read: true. on DB (using one express endpoint). let me know if you have any other doubt .

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know how to go about it. If you can help me draw the mongoose schema and wire it with the nodejs express and sendgrid webhooks. Especially how to track the open event and update it with the DB. Thanks so much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.